# For which $s$ does $\sum 1/p^s$ converge?

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, dirichlet-series

A well-known result is that $\sum 1/n^s$ converges for $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$.

**Question:** For which $s$ does $\sum 1/p^s$ converge, where $p$ is over all primes?

---

Notes:

- Intuitively there are fewer $p$ than $n$ and so the sum might converge over a larger domain, perhaps $s>0.5$?
- We know $\sum 1/p$, where $s=1$, diverges. So by Dirichlet theory, the abscissa of convergence is $s>1$. Is this correct?

Comment: If you know $s=1$ diverges, that's the same boundary point as for adding all  numbers and not just primes,  so you'll get the same answer

Comment: hi @Alan I'm not sure I understand your comment. Would it be possible to restate it a different way?

Comment: @Tariq If my answer has helped you, I'd appreciate a checkmark :).

Comment: $\sum_pp^{-s}$ behaves like $\log\zeta(s)$ as $s\to1$ from the right.

Comment: hi @vitamind - thanks for your suggested answer, but sadly it doesn't help as it relies on a method that I am not familiar with. If there is an alternative explanation, I would welcome it.

Comment: @Tariq What method do you mean? I can elaborate.

Comment: @vitamind the use of lim sup method is new to me, and I wonder if a proof can be done without it. The approximation $p_n \sim n\log n$ is also a little disconcerting.

Comment: @Tariq Please visit [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127241/tariq-and-vitamind).

Comment: @Tariq Why did you not join? I want(ed) to explain you the thing you don't understand yet.

Comment: @vitamind my apologies - I have been suffering tech issues, but am now back. I will join the room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the abscissa of convergence of a [general Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dirichlet_series) of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{-\lambda_n s}$ is non-negative, it is given by
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log|a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n|}{\lambda_n}.$$
Here $a_n,s\in\mathbb C$ and $\{\lambda_n\}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of nonnegative real numbers that tends to infinity. The formula for the abscissa of convergence, which is stated above, is proven in [this](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Eberndt/dirichlet_series.pdf) paper in theorem $5$.

Our series over the primes is a special case of the general Dirichlet series. Let $a_n=1$ and $\lambda_n=\log p_n$, so that $\sum_{n=1}\frac1{p_n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1\cdot e^{-\log (p_n) s}$.  The abcissa of convergence can be calculated with the asymptotic formula $p_n\sim n\log n$, which is proven [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Approximate_Value_of_Nth_Prime_Number), as
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{\log p_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{\log n+\log\log n}=1.$$

For further properties, you can look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function) Wikipedia article of the Prime zeta function.